# How to get specific line in a .csv file and avoid duplication?

Tags: python, powershell, csv

I have a CSV file, I 2 things from it:

1. In column B I need to get only content with "ERROR".
2. After this has been done, I need to get all the information from column G while avoiding duplication.

Example:

```
## Level ##    ## Message ##

Error      ---------------       blah blah


----------
```

I tried to use PowerShell but Python will be also accepted:

```bsh
Param($Work)

if (!$Work) {
    powershell -NoExit -File $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path 1
    return
}

Select-String -pattern "ERROR" -path .\log.log
```

Comment: Please edit and format the post so that the CSV contains sensible sample data. Add both negative and positive results too.

Answer (score 0):

No too sure what the column indexes are for column 'b' and 'g' are, but hope this helps.

You can read up more about CSV processing in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

```
import csv

#where the final answer will be
extracted_info = []

with open('target.csv', 'r') as fd:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(fd)

    #Skip header
    next(csv_reader, None)

    #go through all rows
    for row in csv_reader:

        #Check if column b (looks like column 1?)
        if (row[0] == "ERROR"):
            #Get information from column 'G'
            extracted_info.append(row[3])

#Get unique values only by casting to set then re-casting to list
extracted_info = list(set(extracted_info))
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import-csv "c:\temp\youfile.csv" | where Level -eq 'Error' | select ColumnNameForG -Unique
```